# how to put detail trace of Exception into a variable?

Tags: java, exception, trace

i got an Exception thown and displayed on the console like this :

```
  java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
       at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:148) ~[na:na]
       at com.amfinesoft.epr.stocks.Runner.inferStateFor(Runner.java:806) ~[classes/:na]
       at com.amfinesoft.epr.stocks.Runner.process(Runner.java:417) ~[classes/:na]
       at com.amfinesoft.epr.stocks.Runner.retrieveStocksFromEPRAndProcess(Runner.java:286) ~[classes/:na]
       at com.amfinesoft.epr.stocks.Runner.run(Runner.java:183) ~[classes/:na]
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:765) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
       at com.amfinesoft.epr.stocks.Main.main(Main.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
```

then, i'd like to put into a variable, the last line of my trace

```
       at com.amfinesoft.epr.stocks.Main.main(Main.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
```

in order to write the specific line in an audit.
How could i do that ?

Answer (score 4):

You can `catch` the exception and get the stack trace with `Throwable.getStackTrace()`. This returns a `StackTraceElement[]` (from `java.io`) that contains each line of the stack trace

```
try {
    // your code here
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    StackTraceElement[] trace = e.getStackTrace();
    String lastLine = trace[trace.length - 1].toString();
}
```